# How do you prove that $Y^*(1_B) = 1_{Y^*B}$ given $Y^*(f) = \mathcal{A}(f, -)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a small category and define $Y^*: \mathcal{A} \to \text{Fun}(\mathcal{A}, \text{Set}), \ Y^*(A) = \mathcal{A}(A, -), \ Y^*(f) = \mathcal{A}(f, -)$.  Then $Y^*(1_B) = 1_{Y^*B}$.

I'm very confused.

$1_{Y^*B} = 1_{\mathcal{A}(B, -)} : \mathcal{A}(B,-) \Rightarrow \mathcal{A}(B,-)$ and sends each object $X$ of $\mathcal{A}$ to ?

Please help me understand the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed the mapping $Y^*$ is a functor from the category $\mathcal A^\text{op}$ into a functor category, this means that for every object $B \in \mathcal A$ you have that $Y^*(1_B) \colon Y^*(B) \stackrel{\cdot}{\to} Y^*(B)$ is a natural transformation.

So for every object $X \in \mathcal A$ you have function 
$$Y^*(1_B)(X) \colon \mathcal A(B,X) \to \mathcal A(B,X)$$
this function takes a $f \in \mathcal A(B,X)$ and sends it to $f \circ 1_B=f$, hence it is the identity function: this tells that 
$$Y^*(1_B)(X)=\text{id}_{\mathcal A(B,X)}=1_{Y^*(B)}(X)$$
for every $X \in \mathcal A$ (where $1_{Y^*(B)}$ is the identity natural transformation for the functor $Y^*(B)$).

Hope this address your doubts.

Comment: Thank you!  I will go over your post later.